# Plurk API 40007:missing request token

Tags: php

When I try to get an `access_token` from plurk API, I receive error

> Bad Request 40007:missing request token

I create curl request like in example on plurk Docs

```
$params = array( "oauth_consumer_key"=>"xxxxxx", "oauth_nonce"=>md5(time()), "oauth_signature_method"=>"HMAC-SHA1", "oauth_signature"=>$sig, "oauth_timestamp"=>time(), "oauth_version"=>"1.0", "oauth_token"=>$request->getParameter("oauth_token"), "oauth_verifier"=>$request->getParameter("oauth_verifier"),

            );
            $url = "http://www.plurk.com/OAuth/access_token";

            $res = Common::getCurlRequest($url, $params);
```

I can't understand what is the "request token" means?

Answer (score 0):

The `http://www.plurk.com/OAuth/access_token` url is for exchanging a Request Token for an Access Token.

So you should either have a Request Token that you submit here, or use a different url if you're not at the token exchange phase.

Comment: Erik, thx. Yes a have request token. $request->getParameter("oauth_token") - it is an request token. I do the last step for exchanging tokens - you right.

Comment: Ah, seems right according to Plurk docs. Are you sure that $request->getParameter("oauth_token") contains a value?